# Copy files through sockets in Java

Tags: java, file, sockets

I'm having troubles with files in Java.

The issue is: I'm trying to copy a file (not only text, any kind) from one side of a socket to another. I read the file with a BufferedReader (byte by byte) and write them on a file with a FileOutputStream.

It works fine, but when I open the file it **is not the same as te original**, it is writing the bytes on a text file or something like that.

A piece of code:

```
        in = new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        byte b[] = new byte[MAX_LENGTH];
        File f = new File(name);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(name);
        for(int i = 0; i < segments; i++){
            in.read(b,i*MAX_LENGTH,MAX_LENGTH);
            fos.write(b);
        }
```

Where s is a opened socket (working fine), name the name of the file and segments the number of segments sent through the socket (segments of MAX_LENGTH).

Comment: Look at a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520911/java-sending-and-receiving-file-byte-over-sockets?rq=1 I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but didn't help too much :(

Comment: *I read the file with a BufferedReader (byte by byte)*: this doesn't make sense. A BufferedReader, as all thr Readers, reads chars, not bytes. Readers and Writers are for text. Streams are for bytes. Since you need to read and write bytes, you should not use a Reader. Post your relevant code.

Comment: Thanks too much JB Nizet, THAT was the problem, I was using the wrong kind to read, now with Streams it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You assume that you can read `MAX_LENGTH` bytes with each read call. This may not be the case.

`read` returns the number of bytes actually read from the stream. Just write that many bytes to the output stream in each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Your copy code is wrong. You are ignoring the result returned by read(). Memorize this loop. It is the canonical way to copy streams in Java.

```
while ((count = in.read((buffer)) >= 0)
{
   out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Compare with your code. Make the buffer any size you like, the larger the better.

Comment: I tried it too, i had: fos.write(b,i*MAX_LENGTH,1000);

Comment: That's not the same at all. Re-compare. Try *this* code.