# How to rename a file while send it via socket?

Tags: java

Hi guys I'm using a java socket to send files I want to change the file name when it received to the server or client it will be like server-file.pdf and I'm using FileInputStream,BufferedInputStream,BufferedOutputStream.

Comment: So change your code that writes the file to use a different name.  What is your question?

Comment: yeah it worked I found that fos = new FileOutputStream("M:\\test2.xml"); is where I can add the new name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make your output stream, couldn't you use something like:

```
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream("M:\\test2.xml");
    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println("File not found. ");
}
```

And instead of test2 you can name it to which ever path and name.

**Source, including a more complete example:**

[1] [Java sending and receiving file (byte[]) over sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520911/java-sending-and-receiving-file-byte-over-sockets)