# Unexpected behavior with write and readline (Java)

Tags: java, bufferedreader, readline, bufferedwriter

I'm writing a client server program in which I have to send `byte[]`. So, I'm using following code:

```
byte[] b = {}; //byte array of size 10
w2.write(new String(b, "utf-8") + "\n");     //exceptions etc. are handled
```

On the receiving side:

```
String s = r.readLine();
byte[] g = s.getBytes("utf-8");
//Now, when I print the string here, the o/p seems 
//to be the same as on the sending side but g.length is now 14 here.
```

I'm printing the byte array converting it to string by `new String(byte array[], "utf-8")`

It prints some unreadable characters too, but they match (So I don't think there is the problem)

What can the reason be for this kind of behavior?

This is how reader and writer are declared:

```
c = (SSLSocket) f.createSocket("127.0.0.1", 24910);
w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(c.getOutputStream()));
r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: Well what are the bytes to start with? What is `w2`? Assuming it's a writer of some description, what's it writing to and what encoding is it using? What is `r`? There's *lots* of information missing in this post.

Comment: `w2` is bufferedWriter for the socket.

Comment: And how are you creating it? Put *all* the relevant information in the question. Fundamentally, if you're trying to transfer binary data from one place to another, you shouldn't be using Reader and Writer classes at all.

Comment: Similarly, r is bufferedReader on the recieving side. I did not explain the variables because it seemed obvs. Sorry.

Comment: So, what are my options?

Comment: It's not at all obvious, because Readers and Writers deal in text, which needs to be encoded/decoded before it is transferred over a binary protocol. As for options - you haven't explained why you're using readers and writers in the first place. Why not just use the output stream for the socket?

Comment: So, I'm first converting the byte[] to string and then sending it. (Because bufferedreader / writer does not deal in binary data)

Comment: But *why* are you using readers and writers? You're trying to transmit binary data, not text - so use OutputStream and InputStream rather than Reader and Writer.

Comment: Also, @JonSkeet, bufferedReader and writer are created over SSL sockets. It is working fine with every other text that I want to send/recieve, but not with byte[]

Comment: I'll edit the post for the declaration of w/r.

Comment: I give up, I'm afraid. I've explained several times that readers and writers are meant for *text* data, and therefore they're inappropriate to use for binary data (byte arrays). I don't know how many different ways I can explain that.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet, I think I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `InputStream` and `OutputStream`

May be [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520911/java-sending-and-receiving-file-byte-over-sockets) helps.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: But this is what _vish4071_ is trying to do. He basically wants to send bytes over sockets.

Comment: you should provide some explanation of the problem and your solution.

Comment: I don't know but while googling, that link did not appear (my bad there). I'd be happy with a little more explanation, but this link actually helped.