# java: Transfer a file to the server and get the file from the server in upper case

Tags: java, sockets, file-transfer

i want to send a .txt file from the client to server and get it back in upper case. 
But this code do nothing.can anyone tell what is wrong here..?

SERVER : getting file from client and sending it back in upper case to the client.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Assignment4_Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        byte[] bytearray = new byte[4096];
        try (ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(4444)) {
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
            int count;
            String data = null ;
            while((count = is.read(bytearray))>0){
                data = Arrays.toString(bytearray).toUpperCase();
                byte[] bytearrayout = data.getBytes();
                os.write(bytearrayout);
            }
            s.close();
        }
    }
}
```

CLIENT : sending text.txt file to the server and getting file back after converted in upper case.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;


public class Assignment4_client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("test.txt");
        byte[] bytearray = new byte[4096];
        Socket sc = new Socket("localhost",4444);
        //send file
        int countS , countR;
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        OutputStream os = sc.getOutputStream();
        while((countS = bis.read(bytearray))>0){
        os.write(bytearray);
        }
        //recieve file in uppercase from server
        InputStream is = sc.getInputStream();
        byte[] bytearray2 = new byte[4096];
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        while((countR = is.read(bytearray2))>0){
            bos.write(bytearray2);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: can you be more specific than "  But this code do nothing"? can you debug? does the server seem to be getting and processing the file but the processing doesn't change anything.

Comment: You are messing with the instruction and some are not in the right order. These could obviously throw exceptions, especially in the while loop in the client. You have part of your answer here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520911/java-sending-and-receiving-file-byte-over-sockets) . Remember that flush method of OutputStream does nothing ([link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html)) and it is better to use a buffer size that fit your hardware than trying to read to whole file at a glance (use 4096 -> memory page size).

Comment: @AlexC. After making changes as you suggest code is now working but it write `[116, 104, 105, 115, 32, 105, 115, 32, 97, 32, 116, 101, 115, 116, 32, 102, 105, 108, 101, 46, 0, 0, 0, 0,...]`  into the file in place of `THIS IS A TEST FILE.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code that should help you. But before reading it you should be aware of what is happening:

1. Your client is not sending a 'stop reading' information to the server (read the client code below). That's why the server is stuck in the while loop when it is trying to read the data sent by the client. That is probably why you have tried to send the data back directly to the client. Shut down the socket output from the client side to respect the Socket contract and correctly free the socket (see TCP/IP).
2. The solution given doesn't take in account that the server should stay up after it has done its duty. Then, the server will not be able to serve more than one client at a time. This server is offering a one time service, which is pointless. To overcome this issue you should put everything in a while loop and bind every new server process into a new thread (I let you do that, its quite a joy).

   The server doesn't take in account the whole size of the data an it could possibly run into an out of memory error if the data is too heavy. You should find a way to avoid this problem in a real implementation.

   Both program should catch the exception and log it somewhere so you could be aware of any errors.

   Writing a server is not so simple. You should normally write some kind of protocol with headers and other stuff like that. To avoid that, use objects like ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream but it has some limitation like  constraining your server in the Java world.

**CLIENT**

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Client {


    public void send(File file)
    {
        Socket sc = null;
        try
        {
            byte[] bytearray = new byte[4096];
            sc = new Socket("localhost", 4444);

            // 1. Read the file, send its content, close it. 
            int count;
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            OutputStream os = sc.getOutputStream();

            while((count = bis.read(bytearray))>0)
            {
                os.write(bytearray);
            }
            fis.close();
            sc.shutdownOutput();

            // 2. Delete old file, receive data, write it to new File.
            InputStream is = sc.getInputStream();
            bytearray = new byte[4096];
            // Eventually do what you want with the file: new one, append, etc.
            file.delete();
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
            count = 0;
            while((count = is.read(bytearray)) > 0)
            {
                bos.write(bytearray, 0, count);
            }
            fos.close();
            bos.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sc != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    sc.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SERVER**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server
{
    Server()
    {
        Socket s = null;
        byte[] bytearray = new byte[4096];
        try (ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(4444))
        {
            s = ss.accept();
            InputStream is = s.getInputStream();

            // 1. Recieve data and put it to UpperCase.
            String data = "";
            int count;
            while((count = is.read(bytearray)) > 0)
            {
                data += new String(bytearray, 0, count);
            }
            data = data.toUpperCase();
            System.out.println(data);

            // 2. Send back data.
            OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
            os.write(data.getBytes());
            os.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**TEST PROGRAM**

This one should help you to test your both programs in the same project in an IDE.

```
import java.io.File;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Client c = new Client();
        (new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Server s = new Server();
            }
        }).start();
        c.send(new File("test.txt"));
    }
}
```

Comment: You have not tested this code. The usage of `offset` here is not correct; you are ignoring the read count in the sending code; it is not necessary for the server to read the entire request into memory;  `bytearray` is unused; and both the `delete()` and `createNewFile()` calls here are redundant and wasteful.

Comment: This code what tested and is working for the initial question. How can you say that the server does not need to read the entire request ? Have you ever seen a server doing so ? At least you will need to implement a specific protocol to do this which is absolutely not the case here. Please read the full answer.

Comment: If this code did not comtain major errors about the `offset` variable, why exactly did you remove one of them? And not the other?

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong here is two simple things.

1. The server is reading until end of stream, on a socket that must be used for the reply. The client therefore cannot close it after sending the request to provide the EOS, so it must shutdown the socket for output after sending the request.
2. Your copy loops are wrong. The general form is:

   ```
   while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
   {
        out.write(buffer, 0, count);
   }
   ```

   You are ignoring the read count when writing, so you will write junk at end of stream, or any other time that `read()` doesn't fill `buffer`, which can be any time at all.

Comment: You do not provide anything more than the first answer. It's only re-edit.

Comment: @AlexC. Don't BS here. I provided a correct answer which was already free from the errors *some* of which, but not all, you have *subsequently* removed from your answer.