# java: send large files through sockets

Tags: java, file, sockets, client-server

So im making a client-server based architecture programm where server is sending a file and client receives it.
I have seen a lot of code parts and i also made a lot where i send small files. ex images. In my case i want to send .wav audio files which are large(40mb). This is what i have done so far. When i run my client, it just proceed to download, but never really downloads the file. I guess its because its too large.

How to send such large files?

server

```
public void send_file_to_client(String requested_file) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;

        File FILE_TO_SEND = new File("C:\\ServerMusicStorage\\" + requested_file + ".wav");
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) FILE_TO_SEND.length()];
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(FILE_TO_SEND);
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClientHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        OutputStream os = null;
        bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        os = connsock.getOutputStream();
        System.out.println("Sending " + FILE_TO_SEND + "(" + mybytearray.length + " bytes)");


        toClient.writeUTF(Integer.toString(mybytearray.length));
        os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        os.flush();
        System.out.println("Done.");

        if (bis != null) {
            bis.close();
        }
        if (os != null) {
            os.close();
        }
        if (connsock != null) {
            connsock.close();
        }
    }
```

client

```
public static void receive_file(String requested_file) throws IOException {

        File file_to_save = new File("C:\\ClientMusicStorage\\" + requested_file + ".wav");
        int bytesRead;
        int current = 0;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

        //get file size to create the bytearray
        String fileSize=fromServer.readUTF();
        int final_file_size = Integer.parseInt(fileSize);
        
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[final_file_size];
        InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file_to_save);
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        current = bytesRead;

        do {
            bytesRead
                    = is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length - current));
            if (bytesRead >= 0) {
                current += bytesRead;
            }
        } while (bytesRead > -1);

        bos.write(mybytearray, 0, current);
        bos.flush();
}
```

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9526674/238704) is a proper read loop that terminates on end-of-stream. The write loop is analogous. You'll need to modify them to use the length value that you send before the file.